# Force download of file from another server in MVC using File Result

Tags: php, model-view-controller, file, http

I've got a problem.  I have two completely separate websites, one written in .Net using MVC2, the other written in PHP.

I have links in my MVC site to media files in my PHP site, and I'm trying to find a way to force a download when the user clicks these links.

How could I do this in MVC?  I understand how I can return a FileResult like this:

```
 public FileResult Download(string path)
 {
        var contentType = "audio/mp3";

        FilePathResult result = new FilePathResult(Server.MapPath("~/Content/" 
                                                    + path), contentType);
        result.FileDownloadName = path;
        return result;
 }
```

But the Server.MapPath requires that the files be hosted on the MVC server.

**Addendum**

I also tried doing this on the .php side of the house, using a download.php?file=filepath and setting the content headers that way.  However, I kept getting "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" errors.  [I created a separate question on SO asking why this is happening.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10183923/356544)

Comment: *"Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"* errors are thrown when you try to modify header information **after** your application generated output. You need to make sure that you set your headers before any sort of output is generated by the application.

Comment: on the php front, the rest of the error says "(output started at download.php:1)"  I've checked for whitespace before and after the script.  That problem may be worthy of a whole separate question on SO.

Comment: There *are* already tons of separate questions about this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+modify+header+information+-+headers+already+sent